# Cancel order by customer in Opencart 3

Tags: opencart-3

By default, there is no possibility that the customer to cancel an order from his account. The admin of the store can do that from the admin panel.

We want p Cancel order by customer

```
  <file path="catalog/view/theme/default/template/account/order_list.twig">
    <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[ <td class="text-right">{{ order.total }}</td>]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[

        <td class="text-right">
```

Cancel order, nr {{ order.order_id }}

```
            ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

php cancel

```html
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php 
$customer_id = $_SESSION['default']['customer_id'];
if ($customer_id == ''){
exit;
}
//echo $customer_id;
 
$order_id = mysql_escape_string($_GET['order_id']);
if ($order_id == ''){
exit; 
}
include 'config.php';
 $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
 mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE); 
 if (!$link) {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }
$updateSQL = mysql_query("UPDATE oc_order SET order_status_id = '7' where order_id = '$order_id;' and customer_id = '$customer_id'");
 
?>
<script>alert("The order was canceled!");
window.location.replace('/')
</script>
```

The result

Notice: Undefined index: default in C:\xampp\htdocs\3020\cancel-order.php on line 3

Answer (score 0):

1. You are not pulling the customer id correctly

replace

```php
$customer_id = $_SESSION['default']['customer_id'];
```

with

```php
$customer_id = $this->customer->getId();
```

2. Also the $_GET['order_id'] is best fetched like so

```php
$order_id = $this->request->get['order_id']
```

3. you should use the database object instead of connecting on your own

```
$this->db->query('...');
```

really, the whole code is not OpenCart friendly. you should try reading the [documentation](http://docs.opencart.com/en-gb/getting-started/) to learn more about such things as MVC and how OpenCart registry

if you need any developers help, send a request to me at https://dreamvention.ee/support